# How to save an image in its original size in a canvas after scaled the canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, scale

I have a canvas used to photo editing. I want to save the photos in Full HD. Canvas size is well below this resolution for viewing on small screen. So I apply a scaling on canvas to see the whole picture.

How can I save after editing, the image visible in the canvas in Full HD?

Example: Edit an image size QHD (2560x1440) in a canvas size SVGA (800x600) and produce a picture Full HD (1920x1080)

Comment: What resolution do you want it (1920x1080 I assume)? Can you show your code?

Comment: I Haven't codes yet. I don't know how to start with. I just want an idea to do so. I would manage with the code. I think, i can't use var data = canvas.toDataURL(); :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The size you set with the width and height properties will be the image's final size.

```
canvas.width = 1920;              // actual size given with integer values
canvas.height = 1080;
```

If you need to scale down while on screen you need to use CSS (one of those special cases):

```
canvas.style.width = '960px';     // show at 50% on screen
canvas.style.height = '540px';
```

Alternatively have your actual image as an off-screen canvas and copy regions from that to the on-screen canvas depending on scale etc.

If you edit your image at a lower than the actual resolution then the point of HD etc. is gone as you need to scale up a lower resolution image to a bigger one which will make it appear more blurry due to the introduced interpolation. Always work at the actual target resolution when working with digital images (or video).

Then use `toDataURL()` to get the image:

```
var dataUri = canvas.toDataURL(); // saves a PNG at 1920x1080
```

for JPEG:

```
var dataUri = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg', 0.8);  // last = quality
```

Just be aware of that your mouse positions will have to be scaled the opposite way as they are relative to the canvas element and not its bitmap.